# Cannot open Visual Studio 2015 0xc000007b error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Currently using Vs2015 community edition with windows 7 64 bit sp1 , due unexpected power loss I'm getting below error when opening  Visual Studio 2015

[image: -]

I uninstalled and reinstalled  Visual Studio 2015 still not progress , downloaded depends.exe and opened Visual Studio from it and getting missing dll   below error

[image]

Need some expert advise to solve problem , without formatting the laptop

Comment: Due to unexpected power loss it could be that Visual Studio is not the only app that doesn't work anymore. For start try emptying your %TEMP% folder. You can also try to revert Windows to a previous restore point (google for System Restore). The Dependency Walker image is misleading because your Visual Studio is apparently 64-bit, but DW is 32-bit. Try with 64-bit Dependency Walker.

Comment: @Dialecticus I always use correct platform application when installing , so I installed Dependency Walker also in 64 bit version .Restore point did not make any help at all, any other solutions please

Comment: any expert advise to solve problem